# Why removes String.Trim Tabulator?

Tags: c#, string, trim, tabular

Microsoft Doc says about `String.Trim`

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

But tabulator characters get removed too. Is tabulator defined as whitespace character?
If I don't want `\t` to be removed from `Trim` I guess I have to implement that myself, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Tab character is considered whitespace, but you don't have to implement it yourself. Just use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) that takes a list of characters to trim:

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '*', ' ', '\''};
string banner = "*** Much Ado About Nothing ***";
string result = banner.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Answer (score 4):

Tab is considered whitespace.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) contains a listing of what is considered whitespace in C#, under the Remarks header.

Trim alternatively allows you to set which characters you wish to strip, you may manually declare what you wish to trim, leaving the tab character out and not trimmed.

Comment: That's not necessarily a complete list. As of .NET 4, String.Trim actually uses Char.IsWhiteSpace to determine if it's whitespace or not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx (see Remarks/note to callers) Char.IsWhiteSpace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx

Comment: Yes it seems they added a lot more, mostly in regards to unicode. It's a bit messy to list them all now, so I'll instead just include your link instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tab is considered white-space. However, [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) has an overload that takes `char[]` and remove those characters.